# Como "reconstruir" um arquivo a partir do buffer guardado no banco de dados?

Tags: javascript, mysql, conversão, buffer, multer

estou com uma grande dúvida.

Faço o upload de arquivos e os recebo em um servidor node com a ajuda do middleware multer, os dados vem algo como isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então pego esse arquivo e guardo no banco de dados o resultado do JSON.stringfy() dele...

Quando faço a consulta no banco de dados o que me é retornado as informações armazenadas como originalName e etc, já no buffer é retornado esse array:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

então eu gostaria de saber como fazer para "reconstruir" o arquivo a partir destes dados, tanto no próprio Node quanto utilizando o javascript no próprio browser.

Desde já, agradeço pelo auxilio.

Answer (score 0):

O módulo fs permite gravar ficheiros a partir de um Buffer.

```
fs.writeFile(filename, Buffer.from(data));
```